# Should I call completion handler when self is deallocated

Tags: swift, completionhandler

We all probably have used the pattern below. This may not matter much, I am just curious should I still call completion handler when `self` no longer exists?

```
var uid: String

func asyncTask(completion: @escaping(Result)->()) {
    anotherAsyncTask() { [weak self] (result) in
        guard let uid = self?.uid else { 
            completion(.error) // Should I call this???
            return 
        }
        // consume result
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since `self` is de-initated then it makes no sense to call

```
completion(.error) // Should I call this???
```

as the result is already on the fly here `return` suffices

Comment: I disagree. There is an error case in the return enum. It is for reporting errors, and having self be deallocated is one of those error cases.

Comment: @DuncanC according to your opinion , when user enters a VC , then return quickly before callback returns  , a popup tell him a feedback , that's actually doesn't happen in real apps , the op classifies it in code as an error , the user shouldn't be aware of that ,  also Y you consider self deallocation is an error that should be reported

Comment: Fair point. You have to think about what it means to have self get deallocated before a task's completion handler is called. There may be cases, like a view controller that  a user closes, where you want to just ignore that case, or pass the success enum to the completion handler. It depends on your design.